# Block access to plugins.php for custom role

Tags: user-roles, admin-menu, permissions

So I have a custom role and I'd like to block access to the plugins.php page without using a plugin.

I can remove pages from the admin menu with my functions file but not sure how to restrict access

Comment: which role? Have you considered removing the _capability_ to manage plugins from that role?

Comment: I have created a custom role 'owner', which has admin capability with some admin menu items hidden. I dont want them to access the plugins page, I've hidden the menu item but also want to block the page if they try to go to the url for it

Comment: i dont know if without plugin, but i often use this plugin www.wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/ which pro version